# How to get number of weeks in a current month?

Tags: php

How can I get the number of weeks in a current month *(ex. **February 14, 2018**)*?

My example code

```
$weekNum = date("W") - date("W",strtotime(date("Y-m"))) + 1;
print_r($weekNum);//results 3. Why is it not 2?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way to get week number ;

```
echo ceil(date( 'j', strtotime('today') ) / 7);
```

Comment: That is desame result with my code $weekNum = date("W") - date("W",strtotime(date("Y-m"))) + 1;

Answer (score 1):

```
function weekInCurrentMonth($date) {
    $firstDate = strtotime(date("Y-m-01", $date));
    return intval(date("W", $date)) - intval(date("W", $firstDate)) + 1;
}
```

the above function utilises the below algorithm

> Number of Week in the month = Totals Weeks in the year - No of Weeks
>   in the year of first day of month + 1